# How do I lock table so that a user cannot perform Insert, Update, delete operations on it (Only triggers can)

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions

So I have my table shown below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [CommaSeperatedString] nvarchar(Max) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]) 
)
```

and I would like to lock down this table so that it can only be updated through triggers.

I.e. I don't want a user to be able to run

> - Insert
> - Update
> - Delete

Against this table. It may only be updated through a some triggers I have set up.

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't grant anything.

Comment: CRUD or just Insert Update Delete? (The R in CRUD stands for Read)

Comment: @EdwinStoteler oh yes good spot. To clarify, just `Insert` `Update` and `Delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here **[INSTEAD OF Triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx)** comes into picture.

you can create trigger for `INSTEAD OF INSERT` and `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` and same for delete.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig_INS_Test ON Test
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

   INSERT INTO Test (CommaSeperatedString)
      SELECT CommaSeperatedString
      FROM inserted

END
```

Comment: What if the trigger I have is on a seperate table? i.e. I insert a row into another table (`[TestNormalised]`) which updates the `[Test]` table

Comment: @user1: Then what you have to do is make **instead of insert** trigger on [TestNormalised] table and **instead of update** trigger on [Test] table.

Answer (score 1):

In management studio you can go to the userrole --> properties --> securables.

Add the table here and you can deny rights to the table. 
Deny will overrule any allow rights. So even if the user has another role that says allow, it will still be denied the rights.

More info: [Understanding GRANT, DENY, and REVOKE in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2894/understanding-grant-deny-and-revoke-in-sql-server/)

Edit: If your triggers are on the same table use an instead of trigger, like the other answers said. Otherwise use rights.

Answer (score 1):

yes, using **instead-of-Trigger** we can conditionally prevent the CURD operations from others. But we can grant or deny this operations completely from some users also. For that we are using the commands like

```
GRANT - gives a user permission to perform certain tasks on database objects
DENY - denies any access to a user to perform certain tasks on database objects
REVOKE - removes a grant or deny permission from a user on certain database objects
```

Please refer this sites

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1138/giving-and-removing-permissions-in-sql-server/

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1851/prevent-accidental-update-or-delete-commands-of-all-rows-in-a-sql-server-table/

All the Best.....